# how ca I get variable from ubuntu and insert it to the php file

Tags: php, variables, ubuntu

I  have a php file and I want get exact variable from ubuntu command line

how can I do it?

Comment: More explanation please, we don't read mind

Comment: not enough info - you need to include
- where in ubuntu the vars is coming form
- what you want the var to do
- how php is meant to react to such a var
- and what is you wanted outcome

Comment: sorry for bad explanation, I have an email function and I want to get some variable from ubuntu and insert theme in their places, such email address , fullname and  etc.

Comment: so you have a like a XML table or something??

Comment: not sure exactly what you are looking for, but checkout the docs for `$_ENV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you want to pass the arguments from the command line as follows:

```
php /path/to/www/path/to/script.php arg1 arg2
```

In PHP script, you can access the variables as follows.

```
<?php
// $argv[0] is '/path/to/wwwpublic/path/to/script.php'
$argument1 = $argv[1];
$argument2 = $argv[2];
?>
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: thank you for correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get variable which is returned by function or bash script you can use `shell_exec(command)`.